# How to query all the publicly accessible footways using Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I'm working on an app which helps you meet other people. This app averages position between 2 people and then at that point in radius of 200 meters tries to find all cafes. But as a fallback if cafe is not found I want to use just nearest place where you can walk by foot and make sure that this place won't be someone's property and it's publicly accessible for all people and also I want it to be open space and not some creepy or unsafe corner of the street.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
way(around:100.0, 52.229785, 20.973891)["highway"="footway"];
way(around:100.0, 52.229785, 20.973891)["highway"="path"];
way(around:100.0, 52.229785, 20.973891)["highway"="pedestrian"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

This is what I have but when I queried this I felt like it shows me some private territories and some of those places did not felt pleasant to be in, especially for my example query.

Comment: Sounds like you want to check the access tags additionally. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:access.
Apart from that, adding a query for `highway=cycleway` might also be useful since some paths used by pedestrians and cyclists are marked as cycleway.

Comment: @scai thank you, I'll try that later